# Getting Error while splitting countvectorizered data frame for model building?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a dataset of 50k records which contains both text data and other features (numerical  & categorical data). I have countvectorized the text data and merged the sparse  matrix data from the countvectorized along with other features.

```
cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 5000,analyzer='word') 
cv_fit_addr=cv.fit_transform(data['Clean_addr'])

count_vect_df = pd.DataFrame(cv_fit_addr.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())
new_data_frame=pd.concat([data, count_vect_df], axis=1)
new_data_frame=pd.concat([data, count_vect_df], axis=1)
```

[image]

```
X = new_data_frame.values[:, 1:5007]
Y = new_data_frame.values[:,0]
```

Now while trying to split into test and train, i  am getting following error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-f7d87b3bcca3> in <module>()
----> 1 X = new_data_frame.values[:, 1:5007]
      2 Y = new_data_frame.values[:,0]

C:\Users\AshokEapen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in values(self)
   3159         will result in a flot64 dtype.
   3160         """
-> 3161         return self.as_matrix()
   3162 
   3163     @property

C:\Users\
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have `X = new_data_frame.values[:, 1:5007]` in first line of code?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE, I do have that, i updated the code the question

Comment: So, looking at the error logs, the `MemoryError` occurs when it gets to that line itself. I don't think it even reaches to `CountVectorizer` as well. You can verify by commenting rest of the code and running only one line.

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE, I ran successfully when I commented out  the  last 2 lines

Comment: Does it mean commenting `X = new_data_frame.values[:, 1:5007]` and `Y = new_data_frame.values[:,0]`?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE yes

Comment: ok, not sure how you can resolve it, looks like there is no enough memory for these lines execute, may be you can try to optimize code by clearing variables that are large and not used.

Comment: Not sure why the `nltk` is on the tag. Removing it...